# SQL Pivot column values

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393020/three-column-sql-pivot)(SQL Server specific solution) but were not helpful.

I have two tables, **Product** and **Sale** and I want to find how many products are sold on each day. But I want to pivot the table so that columns become the products name and each row will contain the amount of products sold for each day ordered by the day.

Simplified schema is as following

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id integer,
    name varchar(40),
    price float(2)
);

CREATE TABLE sale(
  id integer,  
  product_id integer,
  transaction_time timestamp
);
```

This is what I want

[image]

I only managed to aggregate the total sales per day per product but I am not able to pivot the product names.

```
select date(sale.transaction_date)
  , product.id
  , product.name
  , count(product_id)
from sale inner join 
  product on sale.product_id = product.id
group by date(sale.transaction_date)
  , product.id
  , product.name
```

This is the situation so far

[image]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You need pivoting logic, e.g.

```
select
    s.transaction_date::date,
    count(case when p.name = 'intelligent_rubber_clock' then 1 end) as intelligent_rubber_clock,
    count(case when p.name = 'intelligent_iron_wallet' then 1 end) as intelligent_iron_wallet,
    count(case when p.name = 'practical_marble_car' then 1 end) as practical_marble_car
from sale s
inner join product p
    on s.product_id = p.id
group by
    s.transaction_date::date;
```

Since your expected output aggregates by date alone, then only the transaction date should be in your `GROUP BY` clause.  The trick used here is to take the count of a `CASE` expression which returns 1 when the record is from a given product, and 0 otherwise.  This generates conditional counts for each product, all in separate columns.  To add more columns, just add more conditional counts.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply but the product names are quite a lot so ultimately it will become a very wide table. Adding conditional statements for each product seems quite difficult.

Comment: Then look into using cross-tab with Postgres.  I have not done much work with cross tabs, so I can't give you a definite answer.

Comment: @Ali . . . Generate the code using a spreadsheet or a query on the information_schema tables.